# PHP change default value in input field

Tags: php

I have an input field i want to give this input a default value but also this value can be changed by the user

here i put a default value the problem if the user choose another value the default value still appear.

How can i appear a value and when the user change this value it will be save.

and this is a date i use a date time picker from this datetimepicker the user choose his value .

```
<input type="text" value="<?php if(!isset($_POST['txt_psd'])){echo date('Y-m-d H:i:s');} ?>" id="datetimepicker1" name="txt_psd" />



  <script type="text/javascript">
                $(function () {
                    $('#datetimepicker1').datetimepicker()
                });
            </script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    function GetDays() {
        var timeStart = new Date(document.getElementById("datetimepicker1").value);
        var timeEnd = new Date(document.getElementById("datetimepicker2").value);
        var hourDiff = timeEnd - timeStart; //in ms
        var secDiff = hourDiff / 1000; //in s
        var minDiff = hourDiff / 60 / 1000; //in minutes
        var hDiff = hourDiff / 3600 / 1000; //in hours
        var DayDiff = hourDiff / 3600 / 1000 / 24; //in days
        var humanReadable = {};
        humanReadable.Days = Math.floor(DayDiff);
        humanReadable.hours = Math.floor(hDiff - 24 * humanReadable.Days);
        humanReadable.minutes = Math.floor(minDiff) - (60 * humanReadable.hours + 24 * 60 * humanReadable.Days);
        return humanReadable;

    }

    function cal() {
        if (document.getElementById("datetimepicker2")) {
            var Human = GetDays();
            document.getElementById("duration").value = Human.Days + " Days " + Human.hours + " hours " + Human.minutes + " minutes" ;
        }
    }
</script>
```

Comment: one can always change text input values unless you have added `readonly` attribute.. There must be something in your `datepicker` or any other code

Comment: how you update the input value?

Comment: it's not a readonly attribute

Comment: @PradeepKumarPrabaharan what you mean?

Comment: share you complete code and are you using pure JavaScript or any library/framework ?

Comment: @m7md problem should be with your datetimepicker js

Comment: @Rishi check above